# $f:\{1,2,\ldots,100\}\rightarrow \{1,2,\ldots,200\} $. How many functions can be made?

Tags: combinations

I need to find out how many strictly increasing monotonic functions
$$f:\{1,2,\ldots,100\}\rightarrow \{1,2,\ldots,200\} 
$$
exist.
And I do believe, that the answer should be $\binom{200}{100}$, but I have no idea how to prove it. How can I creat such functions and calculate them all?

I know there were similar questions, but I need more explanations.

Comment: Since $|\{1,2,...,100\}|=100< 200=|\{1,2,...,200\}|$ we cannot create a surjective function $f$. Hence, we cannot create a bijective function $f$.

Comment: If you can say why you think that answer is right you will be most of the way to the proof.

Comment: This is a good example of a homework-based question! Well done $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Jonas Vitkauskas! What was that? Why deface the question? Are you trying to cover up an attempt to get your homework done here?

Comment: Sh#¤%. Should have checked the OPs posting history :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $f\mapsto f\bigl([100]\bigr)$ maps the set  of admissible functions $f:\>[100]\to[200]$ bijectively onto the set of all $100$-element subsets of $[200]$. The number of these subsets is indeed ${200\choose100}$.

Answer (score 3):

If $f:A \to B$ is a bijection ($A,B$ are finite sets), then the number of elements in $A$ = the number of elements in $B$.

In your question: $A$ has $100$ elements and $B$ has $200$ elements.

Conclusion ?

Comment: For those wondering, this answer was written when OP specified that $f$ has to be a bijection.